# When declaring a field, should I go specific to more specific or vise versa?

Tags: java, variables, field

For example, is it more customary to say ratedVolts or voltsRated? I'd say ratedVolts, but what's the more commonly used way?

Comment: up to you, what a variable is named has no effect except on readability by future/later programmers

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be the one which is more readable for example ratedVolts, countOfHitsPerUser etc...

Answer (score 0):

The name of a variable preferably should be the best name that allows people looking at the code to understand what the variable represents. People even write extra long variable names to comply with this (and with today's auto-complete features in IDEs it really doesn't make things any more difficult). Further than that it really doesn't matter what the variable is named, it's completely up to you.

(In my personal opinion `voltsRated` sounds more like a boolean and `ratedVolts` sounds more like which volts are rated)